# Kafka010JsonTableSource will not auto commit kafka offset when checkpoint is disable

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

I have set up a local Kafka0.10+Flink1.4 environment.

I use the code below to consumer data from a Kafka topic:

```
val tableSource:KafkaTableSource = Kafka010JsonTableSource.builder()
.forTopic(kafkaConfig.topic)
.withKafkaProperties(props)
.withSchema(dynamicJsonSchema)
.withRowtimeAttribute(enventTimeFieldName,new ExistingField(enventTimeFieldName), new BoundedOutOfOrderTimestamps(30000L))
.build() 

tableEnv.registerTableSource(tableName, tableSource)

val tableResult:Table = tableEnv.sqlQuery(sql)
```

After I execute this code, there is always warning message found:

> Auto-commit of offsets {taxiData-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=728461, metadata=''}} failed for group taxiDataGroup: 
>   Commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member. 
>   This means that the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured max.poll.interval.ms, 
>   which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time message processing. 
>   You can address this either by increasing the session timeout or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records.

Whatever properties like below I set in the Kafka, it always shows the warning message above.

```
  {
    "propertyKey": "enable.auto.commit",
    "propertyValue": "true"
  },
  {
    "propertyKey": "session.timeout.ms",
    "propertyValue": "250000"
  },
  {
    "propertyKey": "request.timeout.ms",
    "propertyValue": "305000"
  },
  {
    "propertyKey": "auto.commit.interval.ms",
    "propertyValue": "800000"
  },
  {
    "propertyKey": "max.poll.records",
    "propertyValue": "300"
  },
  {
    "propertyKey": "max.poll.interval.ms",
    "propertyValue": "300000"
  }
```

I am not sure the if Kafka010JsonTableSource Flink1.4 will auto-commit offset. But the test result indicates that it will not auto-commit offset. Can anyone help to confirm this question? Or can you see any other issues in my code?

Comment: Maybe this might help you: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/connectors/kafka.html#kafka-consumers-offset-committing-behaviour-configuration

Comment: yes, in my evn, the Checkpointing  is  disables, and i already set enable.auto.commit = true, Actually , the default value is true. Official document say:
`if checkpointing is disabled, the Flink Kafka Consumer relies on the automatic periodic offset committing capability of the internally used Kafka clients`  so i think the internal kafka clients should commit the offset automatically, but in fact, i always met commit failed warning message event i tried many combo of the properties setting.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting a lower `session.timeout.ms` value than the broker's `group.max.session.timeout.ms` value? According to https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python/issues/746, this seems to be the issue.